# How can I execute code after receiving a paypal payment?

Tags: paypal, licensing, payment, serial-number

I have finished designing a program, and am ready to create a commerce system. Ideally, I would like to use Paypal to handle all the transactions for me, how ever I want this to be done on my own website, and have the information securely sent over to Paypal. I understand how to do this entire process, how ever I do not understand where I would add code to have my server generate a serial code and store it alongside customer information in a database.

The Paypal API isn't very helpful, so I am wondering if there is a variable passed back to the merchant website by PayPal, via a POST or similar, that can be checked to verify that a payment was accepted, and then react depending upon that status.

I understand that I can have it send the user back to the merchant website, but I would like it to generate a page along the lines of...

Thank you for your purchase (NAME)! A copy of your serial for (LICENSE_COUNT) licenses has been sent to your e-mail at (EMAIL).

And then have a script run to automatically generate the serial, send it to the user, and save it in a database.

Any language is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Are you working with [Payments Standard](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#wps) or [Express Checkout](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#ec)?

If you're using Payments Standard you would need to use [PDT](https://www.paypal.com/pdt) + Auto-Return to get data back to your page for display.  That said, I wouldn't rely on it to deliver the necessary details to your user because they're not always guaranteed to make it back there even with Auto-Return enabled.

[Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro) is recommend for this sort of thing.  It will POST transaction data to a listener script you have on your server.  This happens separate from the checkout system itself.  You can automate tasks like updating your database, hitting 3rd party web services, sending email notifications, etc. from within this script.  It also allows you to handle e-checks correctly (only delivery the e-goods when the payment clears.)

If you're using Express Checkout you can handle this within the checkout flow rather than using IPN if you want to because the user is always guaranteed to make it back to your site.  That said, if you're accepting e-checks you'd still want to use IPN instead. If you've disabled e-checks then this would work just fine.